# Get a list of tags present in a paged front page

Tags: php, tags, array

I need a list of post tags, only the tags present in the posts shown in a paged front page. So, my first step is to build an array with this tags. This is what I did:

### 1. Declare an array in the global scope (front-page template)

```
$filtros = array();
```

### 2. Inside loop, get the tags of each post and add it to the array

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    if( !in_array( $tag->name ,$filtros ) ) {
      array_push($filtros, $tag->name);
    }
  }
}
```

I have two questions:

#### 1. If array was declared, why return this warning?

```
 Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.
```

#### 2. Once I have the array working, how can I update the tag list?

I mean, the tag list must be present in the header, before the loop, but the tag array was built after the loop. Can I update the tag list rendered before the loop with an array built after the loop?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`$filtros = array();` will always returns null, meaning it's an empty array.

To make your code works, you can try :

```
   $filtros[] = $tag->name;
```

instead of array_push(),

Hope it works after!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was reading about it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php but, when I try it, the warning is shown for the previous line: `if( !in_array( $tag->name ,$filtros ) )` (array $filtros returns null)

Comment: If I declare the array with content, returs null too: `$filtros = array('some');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php